# Making a vector library in python, but my heading() function has a problem with the atan2 function

Tags: python, angle, atan2

I'm making a vector library for python (I'm pretty new to python) and I'm making a function to find the heading of the vector. Here's the code for it. (I'm using radians for all of this, btw).

```
def heading(self):
    return math.atan2(self.x, self.y)
```

I know that this is broken because when I run my setHeading function (which I've tested already, it works fine) to set the heading of the vector, getting the heading returns a different value. I looked on google to see what was wrong with it, and it said that the python math.atan2 function returns a value between -PI and PI. Fine, I add PI when I return it. Still doesn't work. How do I fix this?

EDIT: I was asked to put the setHeading function up here as well.

```
 def setHeading(self, a):
    if type(a) == int or type(a) == float:
        self.x = math.cos(a) * self.mag()
        self.y = math.sin(a) * self.mag()
    else:
        print("Vector2.setHeading() only takes a float or an int")
```

Comment: atan2 computes "The vector in the plane from the origin to point (x, y) makes this angle with the positive X axis". If not the positive X-axis, what reference are you using for the angle reference?

Comment: Could you show the `setHeading` implementation? I understand that you believe it "works fine", but it may be doing so according to a different expectation from what `atan2` works off of.

Comment: If you need an angle between 0 and 2*pi, then you would add 2*pi to angles returned by atan2 which are less than zero.

Comment: @DarrylG 0 degrees is along the x axis, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel added it in an edit

Comment: @DarrylG when I add PI*2 to it and set the angle to PI/2 I get ~6.28 or PI*2, when I should have gotten ~1.57, or PI/2 as the returned value.

Either way, I don't think adding to it works, because when i tried adding PI/2 it worked for a heading of PI/2 but not for PI

Comment: To map from `atan2`'s result (where the [branch cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts) is at the negative X axis) to the convention you are expecting (where it's at the positive X axis), return positive results unchanged, and add 2*pi when the result is negative - like what @DarrylG said. I'm voting to close this because it's really a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: As @KarlKnechtel pointed out, you would add 2*pi to negative angle values while positive values remain unchanged.  However, based upon your definition of setheading function, this will not change values for set.x & set.y since adding 2*pi to an angle does not change the `sin or cos`.  Can you provide an example where an (x, y) is provided to atan2 but (set.x, set.y) is not provided the correct value using the angle from atan2?

Comment: @DarrylGl I'm setting the heading to pi (3.14) but getting a heading result of ~4.7123, after making the change with negative angles.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is you have x and y reversed in [atan2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) call in  heading function

atan2 function signature:

```
math.atan2(y, x)¶
```

Consequently, change heading function definition to:

```
def heading(self):
    return math.atan2(self.y, self.x)
```